# when startKey is unknown how to implement strategy for couchdb/pouchDb

Tags: couchdb, pouchdb

Numerous readings indicate that skip should REALLY be avoided when doing pagination. As in the [link](http://pouchdb.com/2014/04/14/pagination-strategies-with-pouchdb.html) most cite that using startKey and limit is the way to go. After I get the first page I know the startKey of that page, the lastKey of that page and the total entries. If I have a pagination control with page numbers as buttons and the user selects page 3, how do I get there? I have no idea what the startKey of page3.  Perhaps, I do a simple view up front to go get the start keys for the each page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This page nicely describes pagination: 
http://docs.couchdb.org/en/1.6.1/couchapp/views/pagination.html

So, you can't really have a "Go to page 298", but to have links to the previous and next 5 pages, you can look up a larger number of preceeding and following documents and generate links accordingly. For example, if you have 10 posts per page, look up 50 following keys and take every 10th one.

As for making a "Go to page X", perhaps a background script that generates somesort of cache?